# How to get username in AWS Cloudformation template file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have resources defined in my Cloudformation template file with tags defined like so:

```
  "Properties": {
    "Tags": [
      { "Key": "Environment", "Value": {"Ref": "Environment"}},
      { "Key": "Hello", "Value": "World"}
    ]
  }
```

My IAM username is `my.name`. I would like to add a key named `Creator` to the `Tags` property with value my username (`my.name`). Moreover, I need this value to reflect the username of whoever runs this Cloudformation template. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

I am not aware of any way of referencing the IAM username directly from the template JSON.

However, you can use [get-user](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-user.htmlm) to get the username (either using the CLI or one of the SDKs), and then pass it on to CloudFormation as a parameter, or, if you are creating the template JSON programmatically, just insert it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the user ID as a parameter on the `create-template` API call and add it to the tags using `Fn::Join`. Cloudformation won't do this for you.